# JabRef bibliography in SWP error

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, jabref, scientific-workplace

Hey I have problem with Jabref and SWP 5.5. I add 2 books to bibliography and I have error like this when I'm compiling:
[image]

Whats going on?

Comment: Please post the contents of the bibliographic entry not as a screenshot from Jabref but, rather, as plain text from the bib file. Do check first, though, if the `&` character in `Chapman & Hall/CRC` is escaped with a backslash.

Comment: The 99% of compilation errors due to the bibliography are the unscaped the "&" and "%"  in some reference field.